# Why New Google Cloud Pricing Calculator has huge costs different from Legacy One?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

It is better to use new calculator but i see surprising monthly cost.

[image]

Compare to legacy one with same input:

[image]

Refering to the calculation tutorial from the [doc here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#simple_event-driven_function). The legacy one is more accurate. Which calculator version i should believe?

Comment: The memory choices are not the same (1024 MB versus 128 MB). Invocations are different.

Comment: New calculator version does not support under 1 millions request.

Comment: Follow the answer by Harold and enter the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs are not similar in both tools.

Retry with same memory allocated, number of invocation and execution time.